# Asynchronous Xarray writing to Zarr

Tags: dask, python-xarray, zarr

all.  I'm using a Dask Distributed cluster to write Zarr+Dask-backed Xarray Datasets inside of a loop, and the `dataset.to_zarr` is blocking.  This can really slow things down when there are straggler chunks that block the continuation of the loop.  Is there a way to do the `.to_zarr` asynchronously, so that the loop can continue with the next dataset write without being held up by a few straggler chunks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the distributed scheduler, you get async behaviour without any special effort. For example, if you are doing `arr.to_zarr`, then indeed you are going to wait for completion. However, you could do the following:

```
client = Client(...)
out = arr.to_zarr(..., compute=False)
fut = client.compute(out)
```

This will return a future, `fut`, whose status reflects the current state of the whole computation, and you can choose whether to wait on it or to continue submitting new work. You could also display it to a progress bar (in the notebook) which will update asynchronously whenever the kernel is not busy.

Comment: Thank you!  Searching on `client.submit` helped me identify the relevant documentation: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/manage-computation.html#client-compute .